# How to make an average array of an array with Higher Order Functions?

Tags: swift

I want make new array from my Int array which make average from index 0 and 1 and then make it a new item for new array, like this:

```
let array: [Int] = [0, 5, 10, 1000, 50]

let averageArray: [Int] = ??? // Expected: `[2, 7, 505, 525]`
```

For example the first item of avrageArray would be `(0+5)/2`, second item would be `(5+10)/2`, and so on.

Which Higher Order Functions can solve I use to implement this?

Comment: Are you looking for the results to be Integers (and thus approximate), or Doubles? What about the first/last elements? In an array of 5 elements, there are only adjacent pairs, so `averageArray` would only have 4 elements.

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, the items of new array would be 4, that is why I got problem to know what i should do here.

Comment: You should be more specific about these sorts of details in your question. As you'll see in the answers you got, many people express confusion about exactly what you're looking for, and there's a lot of guessing going on.

Comment: That is right, I should be more specific about it, sorry be the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an algorithm in Swift Algorithms: [AdjacentPairs](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/AdjacentPairs.md)

```
import Algorithms

let array = [0, 5, 10, 1000, 50]
let averageArray = array.adjacentPairs().map{(Double($0)+Double($1))/2.0}
// [2.5, 7.5, 505.0, 525.0]
```

To get the **real** average `averageArray` needs to be `[Double]`. Don't annotate types if the compiler might have a better choice

Comment: @vadian: I need double, thanks for your help it was my typing problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/map(_:)-87c4d) for this. If you need a **solution** **without using Swift Algorithms** then this is for you.

```
extension Collection {
    func pairs() -> AnySequence<(Element, Element)> {
        return AnySequence(zip(self, self.dropFirst()))
    }
}

let array: [Int] = [0, 5, 10, 1000, 50]
var newArray = array.pairs().map({
    (Double($0) + Double($1))/2
})
print(newArray)     // [2.5, 7.5, 505.0, 525.0]
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with your code, if the first item be 100, your code does not works correct. Also the end result array should have 4 items not 5.

Comment: @bulletproofsoftwareengineer thanks for pointing out the issue. Just updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need actually two "Higher Order Functions" to accomplish your goal. First one is called zip. You will need to zip your array with itself dropping the first element. This will return  all adjacent elements of your collection in pairs (tuples).

```
let array = [0, 5, 10, 1000, 50]
let pairs = zip(array, array.dropFirst())
print(Array(pairs))  // [(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 1000), (1000, 50)]
```

Then you can use map to iterate your pairs (tuples) and calculate the average of each pair:

```
let avgs = pairs.map { Double($0 + $1) / 2 }  //  [2.5, 7.5, 505, 525]
print(avgs)
```

This will print:

> [(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 1000), (1000, 50)]
> [2.5, 7.5, 505, 525]

---

Just for fun extending Collection and using reduce along with collection dropFirst method. First create a var to hold the last element of the iteration and assign the first element to it. Then iterate the collection using reduce "high order function" to create your resulting array calculating the average off every element using the last element. after appending the result to your array just store the current element to the last var. Something like:

```
extension Collection where Element: FixedWidthInteger {
    var adjacentElementAverages: [Double] {
        guard var last = first else { return [] }
        return dropFirst().reduce(into: []) { (result, element) in
            result.append(Double(last + element) / 2)
            last = element
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
array.adjacentElementAverages  // [2.5, 7.5, 505, 525]
```